# React Native - need variable to update immediately, but useState is async?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, hook, use-state

Ok, I've looked extensively at [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) and I understand that React.useState variables are async.

This is a problem given that I'm working with a component structured React Native app, and need to set and use a variable immediately upon releasing drag of a component. I am doing this within a callback function of a Draggable from https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable#readme , so the callback hook solution from [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) won't work.

Here's what I mean. I start with these `React.useState`

```
export default function App() {
const [firstColor, setFirstColor] = React.useState('');
const [secondColor, setSecondColor] = React.useState('');
```

Then I update them based on the position of the Draggable on the OnDragRelease callback function:

```
<Draggable onDragRelease={(event, gestureState) => { ToggleComboColor1(event, gestureState); ToggleComboPage(); } } onPressIn={() => {setDidDrag1(true);}} />
```

Here's where there is trouble. I have to set the useState variable based on `gestureState`, then if both Draggables have been dragged, toggle a result with `ToggleComboPage()` :

```
const ToggleComboColor1 = (event, gestureState) => {

      setFirstColor(determineDraggableColor(gestureState.moveX, gestureState.moveY));
      console.log(firstColor); //This does NOT print an updated value
    }

const ToggleComboPage = () =>
    {
      if(didDrag1 && didDrag2)
      {
        console.log(firstColor + " | "+secondColor); //This, consequently, does NOT print an updated value for the most recently dragged 
        // setCurrentColorCombo(
        //   getColorComboItemArray(firstColor, secondColor)[0]
        // );
        // setCurrentKey("Combo");
        // setDidDrag1(false);
        // setDidDrag2(false);
      }
    }
```

I tried using a plain `var` to circumvent this, but those are re rendered / re created every time there's a re render.

How can I update and use these variables here?

Comment: Have you tried with ```useEffect``` with both ```firstColor``` and ```secondColor``` as dependencies?

Comment: @QuangThái can you write explicit code to explain what you mean by this?